# For any square matrix A of rank $n$ and size $2n$: $KerA \subset ImA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $A$ be a $2n\times 2n$ matrix, $\operatorname{rank}A = n$, and there exists a vector $X$ such that $AX = 0$. Then there exists a vector $Y\left(Y \neq X\right)$ such that $X = AY$.

The only thing I've come up so far is to pick $X$ such that it has exactly $n$ non-zero entries in positions where columns of $A$ are linearly independent and all other positions are zero, then I pick $Y$ such that $Y$ has zeros where $X$ doesn't and has non-zeros where $X$ does. It's pretty, but it led me nowhere.

Comment: In the title you ask for non-empty (or perhaps mean non-trivial) intersection between kernel and image. Your formulation in the body seems to mean that the kernel is a subset of the image. - What is it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen fixed, thanks

Comment: If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then $AX=0$.

Take any other vector $Y=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$, $AY=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\neq X$.

Am I missing something? 

You can scale this up and take $A$ to be the direct sum of an $n\times n$ identity matrix and an $n\times n$ zeros matrix?

Comment: @snulty yeah, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just post it here as well if it does answer the question.

If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then $AX=0$.

Take any other vector $Y=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$, $AY=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\neq X$.

Similarly take 
$A=\begin{pmatrix} I_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} \end{pmatrix}$ which is a direct sum of an identity matrix and a zero matrix, and $X=\begin{pmatrix} 0_{n\times 1} \\ 1_{n\times 1} \end{pmatrix}$, ($n$ zeros followed by $n$ ones for example) then $AX=0_{n\times 1}$.

Take $Y=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ where $a$ and $b$ are $n\times 1$ vectors/matrices then $AY=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 0_{n\times 1} \end{pmatrix}\neq X$.

Basically though this is happening when the space breaks up into a direct sum of the image and the kernel. You can imagine one subspace being squashed to zero and another complementary subspace just being mixed amongst itself.